# Как написать условие в гугл таблица IF

Tags: excel, if, google-spreadsheet

не могу решить одну проблему у меня есть таблица где отмечают посещаемость детей в детский сад и нужно высчитать размер скидки если он отсутствовал какое то кол-во дней подряд, если он отсутствовал 5 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 5%; если он отсутствовал 10 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 10% если он отсутствовал 15 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 15%. Важно что именно подряд[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1564444/178576)