# Как написать условие в Google таблице IF

Tags: excel, if, google-spreadsheet

не могу решить одну проблему у меня есть таблица где отмечают посещаемость детей в детский сад и нужно высчитать размер скидки если он отсутствовал какое то кол-во дней подряд, если он отсутствовал 5 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 5%; если он отсутствовал 10 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 10% если он отсутствовал 15 дней подряд, то размер скидки за месяц 15%. Важно что именно подряд[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вы задали два одинаковых вопроса?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: я изменил тему вопроса, но почему то он отправился как новый вопрос

Comment: Удалите лишний.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: не дает удалить изначальный вопрос

Comment: минимальный код написан в выбранной ячейке

Comment: Если отсутствовал два периода - 5 и 10 дней? Галка в ячейке - привязана ссылкой к ячейке? Еще одно. Недели "рвут" диапазоны дней. Это затрудняет расчеты. Дайте ссылку на тестовую таблицу, на которой можно поупражняться.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8XbARCaDAhVupR6XUlHyMQDmNtOSyMaOHdlAA-lkvE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Если ребенок отсутствовал 5 дней подряд хотябы один период, то скидка 5%, если 10 дней подряд то 10%, ну и если 15 дней то скидка 15%
Итог недели действительно мешает решить эту задачу, но если решение есть только если дни месяца не прерываются, то может мы тогда весь месяц целиком сделаем

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA или может если можно как то обьединить гугл таблицу с python.

Comment: @vikttur_Stop_RU_war_in_UA а я выше кидал ссылку, права раздал если нужно можете редактировать https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v8XbARCaDAhVupR6XUlHyMQDmNtOSyMaOHdlAA-lkvE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Извините, сразу не увидел...